# Action Form more than one Servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets

Though it may sound a bit silly,still I'm asking this conceptual and logical(as far as foe me :)) question :

In a jsp page Can I send it's form data to more than one Servlet.. like :

`form action="home","car" method="post" name="f1"` or

```
form name='form' method='POST' action='car','home'
```

Any inputs.....//

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the client side, you can do submit the form to two different servlets through javascript, by specifying two different target windows to hold the response.

HTML:

```
<IFRAME id="firstResult" name="firstResult"></IFRAME>
<IFRAME id="secondResult" name="secondResult"></IFRAME>
```

Javascript:

```
function submitForm() {
    var form = document.getElementById("myForm");

    form.action = "/first-servlet";
    // Target is the name of the iframe to hold the response from first servlet.
    form.target = "firstResult"; 
    form.submit();


    form.action = "/second-servlet";
    // Target is the name of the iframe to hold the response from second servlet.
    form.target = "secondResult"; 
    form.submit();
}
```

Then you should have handlers to capture the IFRAME's onload event to process the responses from the servlet.

Comment: can you provide me some links regarding that.

Answer (score 1):

no you can't do that from regular html form, you may do those calls with some help from ajax.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no. A form can only have one action. ref: http://htmlhelp.com/faq/html/forms.html#two-action

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. What you can do perhaps is have your point to a `MainServlet` and that `Servlet` can pass those values to your other `Servlets`. But this could confuse things with your controllers. A better way would be `AJAX`.

Comment: can you provide me some links on this regards.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is no......
A form can only have one action

But it is possible with different submit for a specific action...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but that may work with the help of

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("yournextservlet").forward(request, response);
```