# How to call multiple servlet form actions in single jsp program?

Tags: jsp, servlets

Now I can call only one Servlet form action n a JSP program.But I want to call multiple Servlet form action in a single JSP program.How to do so?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12705996/action-form-more-than-one-servlet/12706073#12706073

Answer (score 0):

Usually a `HTML FORM` has one action only and you should practice that way only.

You can have multiple `HTML FORM` inside on `JSP` and you can set different action for them.

Provide more details if this is not what you want.